# help with AsyncTask

Tags: android, image-processing, android-asynctask

Hi all i have the following files that make up my app. The activity has a custom view called TouchView which uses an imageprocessing class filters. Filters is process heavy so i'd like to implement AsyncTask so not to lock up the UI. I'm not sure where to start with this. could anyoune give me a high level view on how to implement this? eg which class do i extend the asynctask. The app places a fisheye effect on the bitmap. the level of distortion changes as the user moves the slidebar. Thanks mat

```
public class Jjilapp extends Activity {


    private Button b1;

    private static final String TAG = "*********jjil";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e(TAG, "***********inside oncreate about to set contentview = ");
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.touchview);
        final TouchView touchView = (TouchView)findViewById(R.id.touchview); 
        final HorizontalSlider slider = (HorizontalSlider)findViewById(R.id.slider); 

        touchView.initSlider(slider);



    }//end of oncreate
    }
```

.

```
public class TouchView extends View{


    private File tempFile;
    private byte[] imageArray;
    private Bitmap bgr;
    private Bitmap bm;
    private Bitmap bgr2 = null;;
    private Paint pTouch;
    private int centreX = 1;
    private int centreY = 1;
    private int radius = 50;
    private int Progress = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "*********TouchView";
    private Filters f = null;



    public TouchView(Context context) {
        super(context);
       // TouchView(context, null);
    }




    public TouchView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context,attr);

        //code to get image from camera and sdcard

        bgr2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), bm.getConfig());



      f = new Filters();

    }// end of touchView constructor




    public void findCirclePixels(){ 

        float prog = (float)Progress/150000;
        bgr2 = f.barrel(bgr,prog);


        }// end of changePixel()





    public void initSlider(final HorizontalSlider slider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "******setting up slider*********** ");
        slider.setOnProgressChangeListener(changeListener);
    }



    private OnProgressChangeListener changeListener = new OnProgressChangeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(View v, int progress) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            setProgress(progress);

            Log.e(TAG, "***********progress = "+Progress);

        }
    };





    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);


        canvas.drawBitmap(bgr2, 0, 0, null);


    }//end of onDraw


    protected void setProgress(int progress2) {
        this.Progress = progress2;
        findCirclePixels();
        invalidate();

    }
}
```

.

```
class Filters{
    float xscale;
    float yscale;
    float xshift;
    float yshift;
    int [] s;
    private String TAG = "Filters";

    public Filters(){

        Log.e(TAG, "***********inside constructor");
    }

    public Bitmap barrel (Bitmap input, float k){

// code that places effect on bitmap
    }

}// end of filters class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class TouchView extends View{


    private File tempFile;
    private byte[] imageArray;
    private Bitmap bgr;
    private Bitmap bm;
    private Bitmap bgr2 = null;;
    private Paint pTouch;
    private int centreX = 1;
    private int centreY = 1;
    private int radius = 50;
    private int Progress = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "*********TouchView";
    private Filters f = null;



    public TouchView(Context context) {
        super(context);
       // TouchView(context, null);
    }




    public TouchView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context,attr);

        //code to get image from camera and sdcard

        bgr2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), bm.getConfig());



      f = new Filters();

    }// end of touchView constructor




    public void findCirclePixels(){ 

        float prog = (float)Progress/150000;
        bgr2 = f.barrel(bgr,prog);


        }// end of changePixel()





    public void initSlider(final HorizontalSlider slider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "******setting up slider*********** ");
        slider.setOnProgressChangeListener(changeListener);
    }



    private OnProgressChangeListener changeListener = new OnProgressChangeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(View v, int progress) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            setProgress(progress);

            Log.e(TAG, "***********progress = "+Progress);

        }
    };

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      TouchView.this.findCirclePixels();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {                               
      TouchView.this.invalidate();
    }
}



    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bgr2, 0, 0, null);
    }//end of onDraw


    protected void setProgress(int progress2) {
        this.Progress = progress2;
        new MyTask.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: remeber that in doInBackground you should not using UI thread (you should not interact with UI stuff) if you have to use publishProgress and override onProgressUpdate in MyAsync task and interact with ui there

Comment: @Selvin hi there's a couple of probs when i try to compile it now. in doInBackground eclipse is saying that this method should have a return of Void. so i just added return null. that seemed to fix that. Also in setProgess() MyTask cannot be resolved when i try to instansiate it. Any clue why? thanks

Comment: @selvin sorry had another look and just needed to put new MyTask().execute(); thanks again

Comment: @selvin hmmm it's making the image processing even slower. the slidebar sensitivity has increased but now the bitmap takes a minute or so to load if at all. do i have to async other parts of the app as well?

Comment: you need to wait until it completes (task) or cancel it before start the new task